# Is it possible to convert a XAML resource dictionary style to it's c# equivalent?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am new to Xamarin and UWP - though we are using Xamarin this question is about UWP.

I have a resource dictionary .xaml file. I need to create a c# version of this file (don't ask why, it's a long story).

Essentially I have something along the lines of..

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,8,12,8" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"

...
```

Is there any straightforward way of creating a c# equivalent of this .xaml file?

Comment: Parse it as XML? You could created a typed parser for it if you want to.

Comment: No sorry I mean I need to create a c# class that inherits from the UWP ResourceDictionary (I think) and then add the same properties etc. - Create my own custom style but instead of using XAML, use c#. This may not even be possible but as I understand it XAML is converted to c# classes behind the scenes? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually in UWP, you can get the currently loaded `ResourceDictionary` at runtime and modify the resources.

like this:

```cs
Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"] = Colors.Red;
```

If you plan to modify the resource item and have it work on the current page, here are some tips:

- The modified resource must exist in the current resource dictionary
- Resource reference must be used with `ThemeResource`

After modifying the resource entry, you need to refresh the theme for the resource to take effect

```cs
if (this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Light)
{
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
}
else if (this.RequestedTheme == ElementTheme.Dark)
{
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
}
else
{
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
    this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Default;
}
```

You can achieve your goal by modifying the current `ResourceDictionary` without having to inherit the `ResourceDictionary` class for rewriting. After all, most resources can be pre-defined.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok I resolved this by creating a static style class and adding the setters in a static method, then calling this from App.Xaml.cs.

It solves my problem for now.

Many thanks for your help.